# Socicon font not displaying icons, just letters

Tags: html, css

I have followed the steps online and still can't get the icons to show. I believe someone has had this issue before where the hadn't set the font path correctly. My paths are correct but still no luck.
Any ideas?

HTML

```
<section class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="container"><a href="https://twitter.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="twitter">a</a></div></li>
        <li><div class="container"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="linkedin">j</a></div></li>
        <li><div class="container"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="facebook">b</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'socicon';
    src: url('../fonts/socicon-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/socicon-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/socicon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/socicon-webfont.svg#sociconregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'socicon' !important;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    transition: all .4s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
    -o-transition: all .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .4s linear;
}
```

Comment: Declaring the font in the CSS style sheet.

Comment: check the page source, click the link in the font-face `src` and see if it leads somewhere or not... chances are the link is incorrect...

Comment: @Sam1604 It's an [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) declaration.

Comment: It might be the page source, what would a correct page source be though?

Comment: @Dan_ENZ it depends on where the fonts are really placed on your server... what is the location of your css file and what is the location of the fonts compared to the root?

Comment: I have a folder named A3 inside is CSS, fonts, and the HTML file. Inside the fonts folder is the socicon files...

Comment: try removing the `../`, just make it start with `fonts...`

Comment: Still no luck... are you able to get iit to work? Link to the website ---> http://socicon.com/

Comment: of course i can, but how would that help you? :) are other css stylings working on your page? if not, chances are your css file is not correctly referenced...

Comment: Was just thinking if you were using the exact same code then it would be something else causing it...yea other stylings are working

Comment: Do I need to add these.... .socicon-twitter:before { content: "a"; }

Comment: The question lacks essential information (about the font, about the font files, browser console information that tells whether the font files are actually loaded, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're doing wrong, but if you follow these steps, it should work.

As you say, this is your folder structure:

```
/
fonts/ <-- this is the fonts folder where you have physicallydownloaded the fonts
style.css <-- this is your CSS file
index.html <-- this is your html file
```

In your HTML file, make sure you call the css file correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

in your css file, make sure you're referencing the fonts correctly:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'socicon';
    src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.svg#sociconregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If this doesn't work, chances are that your folder structure is not how you described, so move stuff around or change the references/calls to the different files and you'll get it working.

Comment: I have added the css call in the HTML but still no luck... My folder structure has to be correct, can't understand how it could be wrong... I have a Folder named A3, inside this folder is the HTML index file, a folder named CSS to hold the style.css and a folder named fonts to hold the font files.. Do you have an exact piece of working code you code put on here that I could try?

Comment: the very existence of the site from where you took this font kit from proves this is working and that you're doing something wrong that's impossible to figure out with the level of details you provided... if i provided you with another site where I could achieve the same, how would that help your case? it wouldn't! you'll have to pack around those files and folders, get your references right and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with socicon fonts while using with wordpress. This is how I was able to use the socicon font:
1. Downloaded the font (socicon.zip) from www.socicon.com
2. Extracted the zip folder. Copied the extracted folder, named 'socicon, and pasted inside the folder "wp-content/theme/theme_name_here/...pasted_SOCICON_folder_here..."
3. Modified the style.css (wp-content/theme/theme_name_here/style.css).
   Added this: @import url('socicon/socicon.css');
4. Finally, used the font in my wp post, example:

```css
<span style="font-family: socicon; color: skyblue; font-size: 20px;">a</span><a href="http://www.twitter.com/RenShres1"> twitter</a>
<br>
<span style="font-family: socicon; color: blue; font-size: 20px;">b</span><a href="http://www.facebook.com/link.to.ren"> facebook</a>
```

Cheers :)

[I am new here, so I didn't know how to post code...]

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem years later I resolved it. After downloading files. My CSS:

```
<style>
   @font-face {
      font-family: 'Socicon';
       src: url("../fonts/Socicon.woff?6abp0d") format('woff');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

And then using it this:

```
<div><span style="font-family: Socicon">&#xe028;</span>Facebook</div>
```

You can get code from [font site](http://www.socicon.com/chart.php). This is, of course, just an example, put it in CSS file and use CSS classes as a best practice rule.